# ¿Cómo unir el resultado de dos funciones en otra función c++?

Tags: c++, funciones, bucle-for, dev-c++

El problema que tengo es que en c++ tengo dos funciones secundarias, y al expresarlas en la función principal salen en diferentes lineas.
¿Cómo puedo hacer que los resultados aparezcan en la misma linea?
Las funciones usan el bucle `for`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int cuadrado(int x) {
    int i, m;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 1) {
        m = i * i;
        cout << "| " << i << " | " << m << " |" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int cubo(int y) {
    int i, n;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 1) {
        n = i * i * i;
        cout << " | " << n << " |" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int x, y;
    cout << "NUMERO" << "\t X^2" << "\t X^3" << endl;
    cout << cuadrado(x) << cubo(y);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Muestra tu código. No hace falta ver la implementación de las funciones, pero al menos los tipos de dato que devuelven y parámetros que reciben, así como la forma en que las llamas, el resultado que esperas obtener y el que estás obteniendo ahora.

Comment: No pongas el salto de línea.

Comment: Hay esta el codigo.
Me podrian ayudar en que esta mal.
Intente quitar el salto de linea pero no funciono

Comment: El texto de las imágenes no se puede copiar. Además, si las imágenes dejan de estar disponibles en el futuro la pregunta no servirá para nada. Por favor... pon el código **como texto**

Answer (score 0):

Estás imprimiendo el resultado de la función. `cout << cuadrado(x) << cubo(y);`. Simplemente llámalas. Si no, no controlas cuál se llama primero.

```
cuadrado(x);
cubo(y);
```

En cuanto a la solución, tendrías que juntar los cuerpos de los bucles en uno solo.

```
int i, n, m;
for (i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
    n = i * i * i;
    m = i * i;
    cout << "| " << i << " | " << m << "|";
    cout << " | " << n << " | " << endl;
}
```

http://cpp.sh/565cr

Comment: 1 enlace caído . 2- No entiendo esta parte que dices: "Simplemente llámalas. Si no, no controlas cuál se llama primero". Las funciones igual se llamarán en el mismo orden que en el código original(se ejecuta de derecha a izquierda, no al azar).